# How can you test if a series of observations is significantly increasing?

Tags: anova

For each subject, I have a series of numbers (d-prime) that increase depending on SOA. I'd like to show that these values are increasing up to some certain SOA. What would be the best test?

I did a repeated measures ANOVA that turned out to be highly significant for both subject and SOA but that probably wouldn't help me to say what I really want to say about the data (the above).

Comment: Can you explain your data in a little more detail? e.g. what are the independent/dependent variables, whether SOA is categorical or continuous, etc. Also, when you say that you want to show if it's "increasing up to some certain SOA" are you saying that you're interested in whether D-prime becomes asymptotic at some value of SOA?

Comment: The independent variable is the SOA (stimulus onset asynchrony) with units of time (the variable only takes a fixed number of values). The dependent variable is d-prime (sensitivity index) which also is continuous. Primarily I want to show that the value is increasing but I'm also interested in how I could show that d-prime becomes asymptotic.

Comment: When you mean that SOA only takes a fixed number of values, do you mean that there is only a small number of SOAs, e.g. 50ms, 100ms, 150ms? If so then the easiest way to approach this would just be to do t tests (or an appropriate equivalent) between each consecutive SOA (e.g., 50 vs 100, 100 vs 150. When the differences cease to be significant this would suggest it had reached an asymptote

Comment: Thanks, that was the next thing that came to my mind. However I wasn't really sure if that's suitable as I was told that for multiple means, errors might add up when I do a series of individual tests (I didn't really understand that part to be honest). Is that true?

Comment: Yeah, that could potentially be an issue. You'd want to make some kind of correction for the multiple comparisons that you're running. I'm assuming that there's relatively few unique SOAs, so a [Bonferroni correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction) may typically be used in a case like this.

Comment: Thank you very much! If you can make your final suggestion an answer, I will accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say that in your study you have 5 different SOAs: 0ms, 50ms, 100ms, 150ms, 200ms. One way of showing that d-prime is increasing to an asymptote would be to conduct a series of t-tests (or appropriate alternative) between each consecutive level of SOA, i.e. 0ms vs. 50ms, 50ms vs. 100ms, etc.

As long as there's a significant difference between each level, and the direction of change is the same, then you can say that d-prime is increasing. When d-prime ceases to increase for a range of comparisons, e.g. at 50ms vs. 100ms, 150ms vs. 200ms, then this would suggest that d-prime may have reached an asymptote.

As this approach involves running multiple comparisons, you are inflating your [family-wise error rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate). As providing evidence of an asymptote relies on observing a null effect, you probably want to avoid a situation where your likelihood of observing a type I error, a false positive, increases. Therefore, you may want to consider applying some correction to counter the inflation of the FWER. If you have a relatively small number of unique SOAs then a [Bonferroni correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction) is probably acceptable (and commonly used by others in related fields).